# How to display Facebook Photos inside android app as a galley

Tags: android, json, android-layout, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

In my android app, I want to display all the photos from `https://graph.facebook.com/photoAlbumId/photos` where `photoAlbumId` is user fb. name.

I normally get User Profile picture using

```
 ImageView user_picture;
 userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
 URL img_value = null;
 img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
 Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
 userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

How can i get all images for example   `https://graph.facebook.com/zoo/photos` and display them ListView in android activity?

I want to make it look like : [here](http://cl.ly/image/2F0J2r1o2C0m)

Answer (score 0):

first Check the url gives you the images in browser

Answer (score 0):

```js
try
{
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

    String con2=conn.getHeaderField("Location");
    conn=(HttpURLConnection)new URL(con2).openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
    Log.e("link",conn.getURL().toString());

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    Log.e("Image", "get");
    return bitmap;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
   Log.e("Image", "fall");
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
}
```

[Facebook profile image not getting displayed in android image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006048/facebook-profile-image-not-getting-displayed-in-android-image-view)

if you want to get picture from "http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large",must redirect and handle it manually.

like
[Manually Redirect](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/)