# Facebook profile image not getting displayed in android image view

Tags: java, android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

- URL1: URL to get image from facebook: http://graph.facebook.com/{fb-user-id}/picture?type=large
- URL2: URL where the facebook redirects when URL1 get hit https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t5.0-1/371818_100002856860463_136071413_n.jpg

Facebook profile image is not getting displayed in image view android. That may be because the url i.e.  URL1 to get image from facebook redirects to some other location to give the image. When i use the redirected url i.e. URL2 directly to load the image then it it works fine.

Code to get bitmap:

```
    Bitmap b = null;

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(image_path);
        URLConnection dd = url.openConnection();
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(dd.getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have googled it a lot and i get some answers on stackoverflow itself (and may be a possible duplicate) but didn't get any answer that can solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling i found an answer here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

And this resolved my problem.

The HttpURLConnection‘s follow redirect is just an indicator, in fact it won’t help you to do the “real” http redirection, you still need to handle it manually.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it by using the facebook ProfilePictureView instead of an Imageview

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    facebook:preset_size="small"/>
```

After that you can set facebook id like this in code

```
ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;

profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);

profilePictureView.setProfileId(userId);
```

it works..
also You can set the size to small/normal/large/custom for ProfilePictureView

Answer (score 2):

Here-

> auto redirection works automatically when original and redirected protocols are same.

That's the reason, your `URL2` worked but not `URL1`.

So, if you try to load images from **https** instead of http : "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture"; since image's url is "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/....", `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` shall work again to get you the bitmap.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. But the thing is the protocol is automatically handled by the facebook only. If i am using https then automatically redirected url would be on https only. Yeah i made an error in my question that i must have mentioned URL1 and URL2 with the same protocol and that has been cleared by you so +1 for that. But the issue doesn't get resolved by this.

Comment: Are you saying that you used https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/picture and yet the image is not created? This is not possible!

Comment: what i am saying is the url (http://graph.facebook.com/user-id/picture ) do not have image itself. When we hit this URL then we will be redirected to some other location for getting the image. So that's what i have mentioned in my answer. thank you

Comment: So that's what I already said, that the link with `http` wont fetch you the image but `https` will fetch you since image's actual url is `https`. Anyways, if you are clear in your mind, that's it